# Too many bytes received on my server socket

Tags: c#, sockets, arrays

I have a listening socket on my UWP device.

This the code for that:

```
List<byte> requestInBytes = new List<byte>();

using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
    IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
    uint dataRead = BufferSize;
    while (dataRead == BufferSize)
    {
        await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
        requestInBytes.AddRange(data);
        dataRead = buffer.Length;
    }
}
var ct = requestInBytes.Count;
```

The count returned on that is:

**630784**

On my client Winform desktop I am sending the byte array as follows:

```
using (TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient())
{
    await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(GeneralTags.RASPBERRY_PI_IP_ADDRESS, GeneralTags.RASPBERRY_PI_PORT);
    using (NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
    {
        List<byte> requestInBytes = new List<byte>();

        serverStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

The count of what I am sending is:

**626840**

Why are there more bytes received into my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add the entire buffer array `data` regardless of the actual number of received bytes.

Change the line

```
requestInBytes.AddRange(data)
```

to

```
requestInBytes.AddRange(data.Take(buffer.Length))
```

Comment: Hi, shall give that a go. Makes sense too :)

Comment: I was almost hoping my question would provoke thought and have one of those most read questions attributed to it. But no.. I am just going senile.  Need more brain tablets. :) thanks